# Error de headers angular 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0, spring-boot

tengo el siguiente codigo para recibir mis datos del formulario y enviarlos a mi servicio que cree con spring

> codigo de angular

```
crearCalidadProducto(calidadproducto: CalidadProducto){

    let json = JSON.stringify(calidadproducto);
    let params = 'json='+json;
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');

    return this._http.post(this.url+'crear',params, {headers: headers})
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

pero al momento de realizar el envio por post me muestra el error en la consola

> Error en la consola del navegador

Failed to load http://localhost:8686/calidadpro/crear: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://172.17.0.2:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

gracias por sus aporte

Answer (score 0):

No soy un experto en Java, pero este problema lo tuve yo con Node y es un problema de CORS. Seguro que en la documentación de Spring encuentras algo de momento te dejo este link para que le eches un ojo. Con esto quiero decir que el problema está en el lado del servidor.

https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

Espero que te sirva.
Un saludo.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda te comento que utilizando la Etiqueta @CrossOrigin que tiene spring logre resolver el conviente